# Float precision

Tags: c, floating-accuracy

Due to precision of the microcontroller, I defined a symbol containing ratio of two flotants numbers, instead of writing the result directly.

```
#define INTERVAL         (0.01F/0.499F)
```

instead of

```
#define INTERVAL 0.02004008016032064F
```

But the first solution add an other operation "/". If we reason by optimization and correct result, what is the best solution?

Comment: As the answer says, these are the same. Depending on the context of use of this constant, there might be better ways to optimize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same, your compiler will evaluate `0.01F/0.499F` at compile-time.

There is a mistake in your constant value `0.01F/0.499F = 0.02004008016032064F`.

Comment: But 0.02004008016032064F is calculated through my PC and not through the microcontroller. Are you sure that the precision is the same?

Comment: Yes there is a mistake, the value is corrected in the first post.

Comment: @StackOver It depends a lot of your target-arch/compiler. The best way to know that is to test it in your env. Anyway, using the constant is maybe the safest way.

Answer (score 1):

`0.01F/0.499F` is evaluated at compile time.  The precision used at compile time depends on the compiler and likely exceeds the micro-controller's.  Thus either approach will typically provide the same code.

In the unlikelihood the compiler's precision is about the same as the micro-controller's `float` and typical binary floating-point, the values `0.01F` and `0.499F` will not be exact but within 0.5 ULP (unit in the last place).  The quotient `0.01F/0.499F` will be then within about sqrt(2)*0.5 ULP.  Using `0.02004008016032064F` will be within 0.5 ULP.  So under select situations, the constant will be better than the quotient.

Under more rare circumstances, a `float` precision will be more than  `0.02004008016032064F` and the quotient would be better.

In the end, recommend coding to whatever values are used to drive the equation.  e.g. If `0.01` `0.499` are the value of two resistors, use those 2 values.